# Can't open MS Access 365 Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

Because of work changes, I can no longer use Office 365 and have had to revert to my own copy of Office 2013 Pro Plus.  However, I cannot open an MS Access database (.accdb) because it was created in 365.

Is there a conversion tool or workaround that will revert the file to be compatible with 2013?  It's a straightforward database with nothing fancy implemented (yet).  Just a bunch of tables and forms.

Comment: No, there is no *forward compatibility* ("can an older version know about a newer version's changes") workaround. That would be the equivalent of *I mailed a birthday card to my sister last week, but she moved three days ago and didn't leave a forwarding address with the Post Office. Can I somehow readdress the letter before it is delivered to get it to the right address?* You can't ask about a *tool* recommendation here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  I was afraid of that but I thought I would ask anyways (MS has done "Compatibility Packs" in the past when they changed file formats (i.e.: .doc to .docx).  Fortunately, I do have the tables backed up as xcel spreadsheets (didn't loose the data) and will just have to rebuild the forms from scratch...